# What are the libraries libfuse2 and libfuse-dev for fedora?

Tags: fedora, fuse

I'm making a project and I have to use FUSE. I have to install libfuse2 and libfuse-dev (for ubuntu) but I'm not founding this libraries for fedora, could you tell me what are the equivalent libs for fedora?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hmm not sure this might work. But I believe Fedora uses the Yum package system not Apt. But I found this [link](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=112090)

According to the forum post try this on your favorite shell:

```
 yum install fuse fuse-devel
```

P.S I haven't tested this, since I am not in front of a Fedora machine.